# Tomcat 8, JSF, PrimeFaces, CDI - Weld

Tags: jsf, tomcat, primefaces, cdi

My ultimate goal is to use Tomcat 8 for JSF + PrimeFaces project in which I can use CDI provided by jboss weld.

I would want to use :

```
javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped
javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped
```

with `@ManagedBean` annotation (`javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean`)

I would also want to use in some cases:
`@Named` (`javax.inject.Named`) with `javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped`

This all I want to use it on tomcat.  I do not want to use JBoss / WildFly.

Comment: Following is my code :

Comment: what is wrong in what ??

Comment: Choose either of them but not both (whether using both together works or not). The latter approach (CDI) is preferable as JSF related annotations are likely going to be deprecated in the next release of Java EE (8).